# Run only selective tests on AzureDevops Server 2022 based on Pull-Request

Tags: visual-studio-test-runner, azure-devops-server-2022

I have Azure DevOps Server 2022 and I have a Visual Studio C# Soulution in the repoistory.

Is it possible after creating pull request, based on the Tags provided (see picture bellow), run only the tests, that matches the Tag with the `[TestCategory("2FA")]` attribute.

[image]

Or are there any other way to achieve my requirement to run selective test based on pull-request.